# How do I get the star element in the room with the eight closed eyes?

Tags: botanicula

I'm stuck underground. I've collected all remaining elements (water, sun and forest), and now I'm trying to get that "star" element:

[image]

I guess I should find an eye or something to put on that blind tentacle, but I've looked throughout the level and found nothing. How I can solve this puzzle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One eye awakes each time the mouth is fed a light-blue nut. You have to find the remaining blue nuts.

See how I am stuck with only one eye closed, yet I miss the sun too!

[image: Another play]

Comment: Great! I was wondering what that blue gems for.

Comment: The one I was missing was in the chameleon room, just as an example so you can investigate.

Answer (score 0):

The sun can be retrieved by giving a trumpet. To find the room where you can give the trumpet follow the sign that is an oval with diagonal lines on it. Once in the room, give the trumpet and get to the blue eye. Here, at the top you find the sun ring.

Comment: This question is about the star ring, not the sun ring.